# Is it associative, commutative, have a neutral element?

Tags: group-theory

$$a ◦ b := \frac{ab}{a+b}\ $$

Is this right?

$$(a ◦ b) ◦ c = \frac{ab}{a+b}\ ◦ c = \frac{\frac{ab}{a+b}c}{a+b}\ = \frac{\frac{abc}{a+b}}{a+b}\  = \frac{a\frac{bc}{a+b}}{a+b} = a ◦ \frac{bc}{a+b} = a ◦ (b ◦ c)$$

How can I prove that this is commutative? And it has neutral element?

$A = \mathbb{R}^-$ and have to prove that $(A, ◦)$ is a group

Comment: You forgot $+c$ at denominator

Comment: You should also specify where $a$ and $b$ live

Comment: Sorry, A = R^- and have to prove that (A, ◦)  is a group

Comment: You should add this

Comment: Commutativity is about 10 times easier than associativity. Just compare $a\circ b$ and $b\circ a$?

Comment: The commutatitivity is inherited by the commutativity of $+$ and $\cdot$ in $\mathbb R^-$

Comment: this is not a group. you would need your identity element to be $e=-\infty$, which doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f : \Bbb R^- \to \Bbb R^-$ defined by $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.

$f$ is a bijection and you can see that $\circ$ is defined as $$a \circ b = f^{-1}(f(a) + f(b)),$$
for all $a, b \in \Bbb R^-$.

This just means that you've taken the operation $+$ on $\Bbb R^-$ and "pulled it back" to $\Bbb R^-$ using the bijection. Thus, $\circ$ will have those properties that $+$ on $\Bbb R^-$ has.

In particular, $\circ$ is commutative and associative but does not have any neutral element. (Of course, you can do the same computationally as well.)

Note that $(\Bbb R^-, \circ)$ is definitely not a group.